# How to send data from popup.html to content_script without clicking popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, google-chrome-extension, popup

I see this questions many times but I don't understand . I have a data give me true and false (checkbox input) in popup.html I want  when I  reload web page give me that data true or false . I read documentation  message passing but when  clicked popup then run script I don't want this  .

popup.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({request: "checkStatus"});
```

background.js:

```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse) {
    if (message.request == "checkStatus") {
     console.log(message.request)
     }
    });
```

that code give me "message.request" but when i clicked poup .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send data from popup to content script directly without showing it. 
That is because popup instance lives only when you see it.

The solution is to use the [background/event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages). 
Each time a data in popup was changes - just send it to the background via messaging. 
And after page reloaded - content script can ask that data back (also using messaging).

Comment: You want say i send data to background.js then send content.js i do that but again i cliked popup for runing script  @Deliaz

Comment: @TeymurNəsirli I mean you should store all your settings and data in the background and use popup as an interface to change it.

Comment: i am new in chrome extension   please  little bit explaine  how to send data popup.js ==> background.js==>contnet.js  without clicking popup  .  İf you have a link please share with me i dont find clearly  link.

Comment: @TeymurNəsirli you still need to open popup to make changes and send it to background (otherwise why do you need a popup?). But if your store data in background, you dont need to open popup again, when your content script asks about those data